# How can I push my commits merged with upstream changes back?

Tags: git

This is the sequence of events :

1. commiting changes
2. git pull
3. resolve conflicts (which makes all the files to change status to modified again)
4. commit amend all files (so I'll have 1 final commit)
5. git push (or upload) , I get in the return the following message :

   > Can not upload changes, your branch is behind origin/master.  Please rebase changes before uploading to avoid merge conflicts: git rebase origin/master

If I do `git rebase origin/master` then afterwards it looks like when I do `git branch`
I'm in no branch at all.

So, after rebasing all files are modifies again, so I commit again.
Then I do `git checkout` `master` and then all the process start again from 1.

So annoying. Any idea how to push this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you've fixed your conflicts, you correctly `git add` the files that you've just fixed, but then you really need just a plain `git commit`, **not** `git commit --amend`.  You need to have a merge commit at that point that represents the state of the tree with both your changes from `master` and the remote changes from `origin/master`.  Otherwise you are just amending the commit that you were at previously, and if you try to push that to the remote it can't see from the commit graph that your commit includes the history that's already there.  (In other words, that your commit would "fast-forward" the remote branch.)

If you're really keen not to have any merge commits, you could do `git pull --rebase` instead of `git pull`.

Answer (score 0):

- Commit your changes to a different branch (`topic`)
- Pull from the central repository
- Rebase, which will include fixing your conflicts (rebase `topic` onto `master`)
- Reset `master` to be where `topic` is
- Push `master`

Your changes can only be applied after what is already pushed, so you must rebase your changes onto that.